# Converting datatype before count function yields different result than inline conversion

Tags: python, pandas

I begin with two identical copies of data.

In one copy, I convert the 'Incident Date' to `datetime` before counting records outside the specified range.

In the other copy, I convert the 'Incident Date' to `datetime` in the same statement where I count the records outside the specified range.

I expected no discrepancy, but there is clearly a difference. The first value of 178 is the desired output. I do not understand what is causing the different returns from `count()`.

```
#Establish two identical copies
df_date_test = df_TSA1[{'Date_Received','Incident_Date'}].copy()
df_date_test1 = df_TSA1[{'Date_Received','Incident_Date'}].copy()

#Covnvert to Datetime and ignoring the errors understand this cuts out records from the set which is the reason for the warning
df_date_test1['Date_Received'] = pd.to_datetime(df_date_test1['Date_Received'], errors = 'coerce')
df_date_test1['Incident_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_date_test1['Incident_Date'], errors = 'coerce')

#Count of Incident_Date greater than 2006-12-31 or less than 2002-01-01
print("Incident_Date greater than 2006 or less than 2002 (x):")
print((df_date_test['Incident_Date']
       [~(pd.to_datetime(df_date_test['Incident_Date'], errors = 'coerce').between('2002-01-01','2006-12-31'))].count()))

x = (df_date_test['Incident_Date']
       [~(pd.to_datetime(df_date_test['Incident_Date'], errors = 'coerce').between('2002-01-01','2006-12-31'))])

print("Incident_Date greater than 2006 or less than 2002 (x1):")
print((df_date_test1['Incident_Date']
       [~(df_date_test1['Incident_Date'].between('2002-01-01','2006-12-31'))].count()))

x1 = (df_date_test1['Incident_Date']
       [~(df_date_test1['Incident_Date'].between('2002-01-01','2006-12-31'))])


#Count of Date_Received greater than 2006-12-31 or less than 2002-01-01

print("Date_Received greater than 2006 or less than 2002:")
print((df_date_test['Date_Received']
       [~(pd.to_datetime(df_date_test['Date_Received'], errors = 'coerce').between('2002-01-01','2006-12-31'))].count()))


output:
Incident_Date greater than 2006 or less than 2002 (x):
178
Incident_Date greater than 2006 or less than 2002 (x1):
109
```

Update:
Minimum Reproducible Example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Incident_Date':['2009-01-01','2008-01-01','2007-01-01','2006-01-01', '01-JUL-0200 00:00']}) 
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Incident_Date':['2009-01-01','2008-01-01','2007-01-01','2006-01-01', '01-JUL-0200 00:00']})

print("Incident_Date greater than 2006 or less than 2002 (x):")
print((df['Incident_Date']
       [~(pd.to_datetime(df['Incident_Date'], errors = 'coerce').between('2002-01-01','2006-12-31'))].count()))

# x excludes dates without a year, formatted with string (i.e. 01-JUL-0200 00:00)
# The difference is that x is still a dataframe object
x = (df['Incident_Date']
       [~(pd.to_datetime(df['Incident_Date'], errors = 'coerce').between('2002-01-01','2006-12-31'))])

#Covnvert to Datetime and ignoring the errors understand this cuts out records from the set which is the reason for the warning
df1['Incident_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Incident_Date'], errors = 'coerce')

#Count of Incident_Date greater than 2006-12-31 or less than 2002-01-01
print("Incident_Date greater than 2006 or less than 2002 (x1):")
print((df1['Incident_Date']
       [~(pd.to_datetime(df1['Incident_Date'], errors = 'coerce').between('2002-01-01','2006-12-31'))].count()))

# x1 includes dates without a year, formatted with string (i.e. 01-JUL-0200 00:00)
# The difference is that x1 is a series of datetime64 data
x1 = (df1['Incident_Date']
       [~(pd.to_datetime(df1['Incident_Date'], errors = 'coerce').between('2002-01-01','2006-12-31'))])

Output:
Incident_Date greater than 2006 or less than 2002 (x):
4
Incident_Date greater than 2006 or less than 2002 (x1):
3
```

Comment: Update: I have determined the discrepancy occurs because x is datatype `object`, and x1 is datatype `datetime64`. I don't understand why I am getting different results though. Wouldn't they both be datetime at the time the function `count()` was called. How does `count()` work differently with dataframe objects vs datetime?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As an aside, why did you delete your other question?

Comment: @AMC I deleted the question because I supposed it would not do the community well to have a question with no solution...

Comment: It didn't have a solution *yet*. I don't think it would be terribly difficult to solve.

Comment: @AMC I'm sorry, I realized my error was I produced the 'MRE' as you suggested, and that Alex's solution worked, which is why I didn't think it was valuable for the community.

Comment: _I realized my error was I produced the 'MRE' as you suggested_ What do you mean? _and that Alex's solution worked, which is why I didn't think it was valuable for the community._ That's fair.

Comment: "my error *when* "

Comment: Ah, got it. Glad you figured things out! :)

Comment: I realized in the example above that the datatypes are different, but I don't understand how that causes `count()` to behave differently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222389/discussion-between-amc-and-rastawolf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`to_datetime` fails to parse `"01-JUL-0200 00:00"`, and since `errors="coerce"` the resulting value is `NaT`, which isn't counted as a value by the `Series.count()` method.

Here is a simpler way of reproducing the issue:

```py
import pandas as pd

data_raw = pd.Series(
    data=["2009-01-01", "2008-01-01", "2007-01-01", "2006-01-01", "01-JUL-0200 00:00"],
    dtype="string",
    name="Incident_Date",
)

data_parsed = pd.to_datetime(arg=data_raw, errors="coerce")

print(f"Data before parsing dates:\n{data_raw}\n")
print(f"Data after parsing dates:\n{data_parsed}\n")

print(f"{data_raw.count()=}")
print(f"{data_parsed.count()=}")
```

Output:

```
Data before parsing dates:
0           2009-01-01
1           2008-01-01
2           2007-01-01
3           2006-01-01
4    01-JUL-0200 00:00
Name: Incident_Date, dtype: string

Data after parsing dates:
0   2009-01-01
1   2008-01-01
2   2007-01-01
3   2006-01-01
Name: Incident_Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

data_raw.count()=5
data_parsed.count()=4
```